# How to load the same QML file and pass them different properties

Tags: qt, qml

I have one index.qml file that consist of two rectangles that fill the screen in proportions ~ 3:1. In both of them i load the same window.qml file. What i need is to assaign different values to property ORIENT so window.qml will behaves a little different.

Look at the examle below. This ORINET is just to show what i would like to achive...

**index.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: rootA
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width * 0.65

    // set some property or function so it will be seen in loaded window.qml
    // sth like:
    property ORINET: "horizontal"

    Loader {
        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.top: parent.top;
        anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        source: "window.qml"
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: rootB
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width * 0.35

    // set some property or function so it will be seen in loaded window.qml
    // sth like:
    property ORINET: "vertical"

    Loader {
        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.top: parent.top;
        anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        source: "window.qml"
    }
}
```

**window.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: windowBox
    state [
        ...
    ]
    ...
    Component.onCompleted: {
        windowBox.state = ORINET
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) you can give a property to the `Loader` which will be available to the loaded item as well:

```
Loader {
    anchors.fill: parent
    property int ORINET: "vertical
    source: "window.qml"
}
```

window.qml:

```
Rectangle {

    states: [
        ...
    ]
    state: ORINET
}
```

Please note that in QtCreator the `state: ORINET` might look italic and blue as if it doesn't exist, but this is just the editor

Comment: I didn't tailor to your example because I don't entirely understand how you plan to use the state, is it the QML States mechanism or not?

Comment: @pi.314 I edited my answer to reflect your situation more. Please also note you can just do `anchors.fill: parent` instead of all four side separately ;-)